# Airflow connection type File (path)

Tags: airflow

Hello everyone I'm playing with Airflow, I'm reading this helpful [tutorial](https://gtoonstra.github.io/etl-with-airflow/index.html). I'm asking help to understand better how Admin->Connection works regarding Conn Type: File (path). 
I suppose this type of connection is to have local filesystem folder accessible by my operator?

Comment: Ok what i just missing is the fact that i have to specify key:value style in Extra field on my connection like this: {"path": "/my/path"}.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just understand how to configure a connection for a local file because of your comment, thanks @desimetallica. I will put it here for the next one that will need it.

If the local path should be the `dags` folder and you are running airflow inside a docker it should be like that:
[image]