# Airflow FTP connection : Specify default directory

Tags: ftp, connection-string, airflow

How to specify the default directory in the FTP connection in Airflow?

The following fields are available for **Conn Type = FTP**

> Schema
>   Port
>   Extra

The Schema will not work when the directory name is specified there.

I am looking for what key/value pair is required in the Extra field, something like this [(as specified in this post)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151610/airflow-connection-type-file-path?rq=1)

> {"path": "/my/path"}

I have tried "path", "directory" and "cwd"

What works?

Answer (score 1):

You could enter additional information such as the path in the extra-field. However, using or accessing the data in, f.e. an [FTPSensor](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/sensors/ftp_sensor.py) requires you to customise (i.e. subclass) either the FTPSensor and/or the FTPHook according to your needs.

There is an example using the extra-data within a Hook [here](https://airflow.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/airflow/hooks/mysql_hook.html), it`s quite straightforward to build a custom FTPHook/FTPSensor that recognises your extra-data. F.e., the existing [FTPHook](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/hooks/ftp_hook.py) already uses some of the extra-data (setting the passive-mode) - just extend or modify by subclassing the existing FTPHook.

It would be helpful to see how you use the FTP-Connection within a DAG.